# Getting an error "Abort Called" while solving a maximum subarray problem

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic-programming

So the problem is given an array we have to find the maximum possible sum among:

1. all nonempty subarrays.
2. all nonempty subsequences.

**Example:**
arr = [-1,2,3,-4,5,10]

The maximum subarray sum is comprised of elements at inidices [1-5] Their sum is 2+3+-4+5+10 =16 The maximum subsequence sum is comprised of elements at indices [1,2,4,5] and their sum is [2,3,5,10] = 20

I tried solving this.. But for large arrays (for lengths > 50k) I am getting an error "Abort Called".
What is the reason behind this error?! Is it that my code isn't optimised?

```
 function maxSubarray(arr) {
      let subsequenceSum = 0
    
      for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < 0 ) continue
        else subsequenceSum += arr[i]
    
      }
      if (!subsequenceSum) {
        subsequenceSum = Math.max(...arr)
      }
    
      const allsubArrays = []
      const sumOfEachSubArr = []
    
      for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (let j = i ; j < arr.length; j++) {
          const tempArr = arr.slice(i, j+1)
          allsubArrays.push(tempArr)
        }
      }
     
    
      // Getting sum of all subarrays
      for (let subArr of allsubArrays) {
        let sum = subArr.reduce((sum, curVal) => {
          return sum + curVal
        }, 0)
        sumOfEachSubArr.push(sum)
      }
      let subArraySum = Math.max(...sumOfEachSubArr)
    
      const result = []
      result.push(subArraySum,subsequenceSum )
      console.log(result)
      return result
    
    
    }
```

Comment: "Abort called" - running out of memory or stack? Timing out? What is the *context* of execution, and *exact* error message?

Comment: Showing nothing more than "Abort Called".

Comment: Where is the code executed (ie. the context of execution)? Chrome? Node? An online puzzle checker?

Comment: Before even looking at your algo, `Math.max(...arr)` can [crash the engine](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_with_many_values). Don't use it on an array of >50k elements (MDN says there's a limit of [65536](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#using_apply_and_built-in_functions) on one implementation). After looking at your algo, there are triply nested loops O(n^3) to build `allsubArrays`. Probably not going to cut it.

Comment: @ggorlen No its just quadratic run time.There are more than 2 for loops. But at max only 2 are nested. I only wanted to know the cause of the error.

Comment: @user2864740 it was a problem on hackerrank

Comment: `slice` runs a loop and is O(n), that's triply-nested because it's inside two `for` loops bound to `n`. If it's a Hackerrank problem, providing a link is helpful.

Comment: @ggorlen Sure! Here it is. https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/maxsubarray/problem?h_r=internal-search

Comment: @ggorlen My question was what was in the code that resulted in this error. It wasn't terminated due to timeout so the running time may not be the actual reason. Anyways, there are couple more  strategies to solve this problem in linear time like Kadane's algorithm.